# Paginate data from different queries in FIRESTORE

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I want to present a list of object in my web app but these objects came from different queries because firestore doesn't support "or condition" it just support it with arrays in "array_contains_any". Then, I need to retrieve that information from two queries and I would like to merge the queries on a single one but I don't know if it is possible. On the other hand,I think I could paginate it separately but I can't do sorting properly because It will order my documents separately that's why I want to concatenate the queries on a single one. I'd greatly appreciate your help.

These are the queries:

```
query1 = coll_ref.where(fieldname,u'==',value)

query2 = coll_ref.where(u'fieldname',u'array_contains',value)
```

I would like to:

```
query.sort(fieldname).limit(3)
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I see a potential solution to be to run query1 and query2, sort them by fieldname, and limit them by three, then in your frontend code, sort those responses by fieldname and return the first three. For example (pseudocode):

```
query1results = coll_ref.where(fieldname,u'==',value).sort(fieldname).limit(3)

query2results = coll_ref.where(u'fieldname',u'array_contains',value).sort(fieldname).limit(3)

combined = query1results.concatenate(query2results).unique()

combined.sort(fieldname)[:3]
```

I am not sure what your language is, so I can't give you an exact implementation. In the above example, lets says that `query1results` returns `['apple', 'banana', 'orange']` and `query2results` returns `['banana', 'cucumber', 'kiwi']`, the result of `query1results.concatenate(query2results).unique` would be `['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'kiwi']`, then sort and limit three so the result would be `['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber']` which is equivalent to `query.where(query1 or query2).sort(fieldname).limit(3)`

Comment: Thank you very much Theodore! It seems to me a feasible path if the user just move for next and previous page. Nevertheless, I would like the user be able to move on the different pages, what do you think is it feasible with firestore queries?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by pages, do you mind clarifying

Comment: For example:    First << 1 2 3 4 >> Last    That's how I want my user navigate through the website @Theodore_Kim :)